# Can't load data from file saved in local device

Tags: ios, core-data

This should be super simple but somehow I can't figure it out.

I have an image that I'm saving locally in the device and I'm using Core Data to store the location of where the file is saved. Core data is not saving the file itself, just the location.

I'm doing it like this:

```
- (NSString *) saveFileToLocalFilePath
{
    card_FileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@.png",
                     self.card_name,
                     self.card_issuer];

    NSArray *arrayPaths =
    NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                        NSDocumentDirectory,
                                        NSUserDomainMask,
                                        YES);
    NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    path = [path stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
    path = [path stringByAppendingString:card_FileName];

    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(imageTaken) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

    return path;
}

- (void) generateNewCoreDataCardWithFilePath:(NSString *)filePath
{
    Card *card = (Card *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Card"
                                                        inManagedObjectContext:[CoreDataHelper getManagedObjectContext]];
    card.card_name = self.card_name;
    card.card_issuer = self.card_issuer;
    card.card_type = self.card_type;
    card.card_image_location = card_FileName; // this should just be the "DefaultCardName_DefaultCardIssuer.png" part
}
```

This then saves the file to this location:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/E02566CA-B992-41AE-9B47-51903448015E/Documents/DefaultCardName_DefaultCardIssuer.png
```

I believe this part works. The issue I'm having is retrieving the file.
Here's what I'm doing to open the file:

```
Card *card = [[self fetchedResultsController]objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

NSArray *arrayPaths =
NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                    NSDocumentDirectory,
                                    NSUserDomainMask,
                                    YES);
NSString *path = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
path = [path stringByAppendingString:@"/"];
path = [path stringByAppendingString:card.card_image_location];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

The issue is that data is returning nil every single time.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

**Edit**
Got it to work by changing the way I call the data, by using:

```
[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]
```

Comment: *"I believe this part works"*, that is not enough: check the return value of `writeToFile`, that will tell you if it worked or not. Provide some debuggin information: does the file actually get saved, does the data get actually saved by CoreData, does the data get extracted by CoreData. All theses steps might result in you not beeing able to read the file.

Comment: The file does get saved and it even shows up in the "devices" section in Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please test whether or not file gets actually saved with the following code?

```
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) firstObject];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"card.card_image_location"];
BOOL fileExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath];
```

Comment: If I change the path component to @"DefaultCardName_DefaultCardIssuer.png" (which is the file name) the response is yes, so the file does exist.